# pyarrow causing segfault randomly

Tags: python, cython, pyarrow

I'm using pyarrow to read feather files. I'm randomly getting the following segfault error.

[image]

I initially thought its because of some bug in my cython code, but then even after removing all cython calls, I get this error randomly.

The python code is very simple read

```py
for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
    index_data = ds.dataset(INDEX_DATA_PATH / self.ticker / str(year) / 'indexed_table.feather',
                            format='feather')

    index_data = index_data.to_table()
    trade_days = self.get_trading_days(year)

    options_data = ds.dataset(OPTIONS_DATA_PATH / self.ticker / self.expiry_type / str(year), format='feather')
    options_data = options_data.to_table(
        filter=(
                (ds.field('dt') >= trade_days[0]) & (ds.field('dt') <= trade_days[-1])
        ),
        columns=options_data_columns
    )

    expiry_dts = [x.as_py() for x in pc.unique(options_data['expiry_dt'])]
    expiry_dts.sort()
```

I'm working in a conda env.
pyarrow version is `pyarrow==5.0.0`

os is `openSUSE Leap 15.2`

It is highly random like approximately one out of every 5 runs segfaults

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of PyArrow are you using? From what source (pip, conda-forge, etc.)? Are you able to get a backtrace? And are you able to share the file or data?

Comment: pyarrow version is 5. its a conda env. The feather file is huge to share.

Comment: Thank you for filing a JIRA issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-13649 I will follow up there.

Comment: Thanks @li.davidm